# What is different of Config and ContainerConfig of docker inspect?

Tags: docker

I use `docker inspect` to get the image information. I find there are `Config` and `ContainerConfig` in the output, and most value are the same, except the `CMD`.

In practice, the `Config` take effect. For I must add cmd in the run command.

`$ docker run -it debian bash`

I wonder what is the difference of the two items?

```
$ docker inspect debian
[
{
    "Id": "7abab0fd74f97b6b398a1aca68735c5be153d49922952f67e8696a2225e1d8e1",
    ......
    "ContainerConfig": {
        "Hostname": "e5c68db50333",
        "Domainname": "",
        "User": "",
        "AttachStdin": false,
        "AttachStdout": false,
        "AttachStderr": false,
        "Tty": false,
        "OpenStdin": false,
        "StdinOnce": false,
        "Env": null,
        "Cmd": [
            "/bin/sh",
            "-c",
            "#(nop) CMD [\"/bin/bash\"]"
        ],
        "Image": "d8bd0657b25f17eef81a3d52b53da5bda4de0cf5cca3dcafec277634ae4b38fb",
        "Volumes": null,
        "WorkingDir": "",
        "Entrypoint": null,
        "OnBuild": null,
        "Labels": {}
    },
    "Config": {
        "Hostname": "e5c68db50333",
        "Domainname": "",
        "User": "",
        "AttachStdin": false,
        "AttachStdout": false,
        "AttachStderr": false,
        "Tty": false,
        "OpenStdin": false,
        "StdinOnce": false,
        "Env": null,
        "Cmd": [
            "/bin/bash"
        ],
        "Image": "d8bd0657b25f17eef81a3d52b53da5bda4de0cf5cca3dcafec277634ae4b38fb",
        "Volumes": null,
        "WorkingDir": "",
        "Entrypoint": null,
        "OnBuild": null,
        "Labels": {}
    },
    ......
}
]
```

Answer (score 25):

As mentioned in [issue 18880](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/18880), regarding `ContainerConfig`:

> What you're seeing there is related to the history of how the image was created.
> Try running `docker history ...` on your image and you'll see the complete history.
> Docker will place the `Dockerfile` commands into the `CMD` section as a way of keeping track of how that layer/container was created.
> Its really only used for cache-lookup purposes (internal docker processing) and not meant to be used by the user.

It is also visible in [`image/image.go`](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/9842c7a741ee480c71bfd8e71e1f22893d010411/image/image.go#L32) as:

```golang
// ContainerConfig is the configuration of the container that is committed into the image
ContainerConfig container.Config `json:"container_config,omitempty"`
```

For instance, [issue 17780](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/17780#issuecomment-154614319) illustrates an empty `ContainerConfig`:

> The `ContainerConfig` of an image is the container the image was generated from.
> In the case of your image, it wasn't generated from a container, but from running `docker import`.

Comment: If I create the image from `Dockerfile`. The `ContainerConfig` is from the `FROM:image`?

Comment: @firelyu it is from the last layer as executed by docker build from the last line of the Dockerfile.